# cocos2d-x]In box2d, didn't make polygon with vertex correctly

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d

```
        {
            b2BodyDef bodyDef;
            bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
            bodyDef.position.Set(location.x / PTM_RATIO, location.y / PTM_RATIO);
            bodyDef.userData = pSprite;
            //bodyDef.userData = nullptr;

            b2Body* body = _world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
            body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(1, 0));

            b2PolygonShape poly;

            b2Vec2 vertices[7];
            vertices[0].Set(0, 0);
            vertices[1].Set(1, 0);
            vertices[2].Set(1, 1);
            vertices[3].Set(0.75f, 1);
            vertices[4].Set(0.5f, 1.5f);
            vertices[5].Set(0.25f, 1);
            vertices[6].Set(0, 1);
            poly.Set(vertices, 7);

            b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

            fixtureDef.shape = &poly;
            fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
            body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
        }
```

i make box2d's body with vertex value.

[image]
in code's my vertex point's shape is like upper picture.

(it's using b2ChainShape, so inner is empty)

[image]
but maked bodyshape is that.

Why do these differences arise?

Can't i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**`b2PolygonShape` cannot be used for [concave polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon); it's only designed for [convex polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon).**

The implementation of the `b2PolygonShape` uses a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) calculating algorithm which will turn the set of points from what you intended (as shown in your first image) to what you got (as shown in your second image).

This is listed as a [common mistake](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-biggest-mistakes-made-by-new-users): using `b2Polygon` to create concave polygons.

You can use a `b2ChainShape` as you've referenced.

**If the inner area being empty is not what you want, you can build up your concave shape using a set of convex polygons.**

Just two convex polygon suffice to create the first shape you've shown. One of these convex polygons would be a triangle and the other a rectangle (or square).

Hope this helps.